# unable to connect to XQuartz host

Tags: x11, xquartz

Is anyone else unable to connect to the XQuartz host? I haven't found any recent information on this from google, so maybe I am doing something wrong.

When I click on the download link website but nothing happens. I also tried with curl (below). I am running OS 10.8.5, if this helps.

$ curl http://xquartz.macosforge.org/downloads/SL/XQuartz-2.7.5.dmg

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://xquartz-dl.macosforge.org/SL/XQuartz-2.7.5.dmg">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2 Server at xquartz.macosforge.org Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

$ curl http://xquartz-dl.macosforge.org/SL/XQuartz-2.7.5.dmg

curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The download link seems to be down at that host. Here is a [mirror](http://thammuz.tchpc.tcd.ie/mirrors/static.macosforge.org/SL/) and a [direct link](http://thammuz.tchpc.tcd.ie/mirrors/static.macosforge.org/SL/XQuartz-2.7.5.dmg).